# Categorical Value placement after transposing another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have a situation where I need to transform my row level data to column level. The unique identifier on which this dataset lays consists of recurrent values. The dataset looks like this :

```
ID       Rating      Rating_Year
1        A           2016
1        B           2017
1        C           2018
2        D           2017
2        E           2018
```

Now I need to transpose the column Rating_year as

```
Rating_year_2016    Rating_year_2017  Rating_year_2018
```

and get the final output as :

```
ID       Rating_Year_2016     Rating_Year_2017   Rating_Year_2018
1        A                    B                    C
2        No Rating            D                    E
```

This is a categorical value placement problem hence no existing solution worked for me on SO

I have tried the following code that gives me the right answer but I need to store this into a dataframe so that indexing cna be tackled properly going forward

```
df1=df.set_index(['ID','Rating_Year']).unstack()['Rating']
```

Comment: Can you add your not working solution?

Comment: Do you try `df = df.pivot('ID','Rating_Year','Rating')` ?

Comment: Or if not working `df.pivot_table(index='ID',columns='Rating_Year',values='Rating', aggfunc=','.join)` ?

Comment: I have added my code. But it is working incorrectly. I need to get the desired output and that too stored in a data frame.

Comment: `df1=df.set_index(['ID','Rating_Year'])['Rating'].unstack().reset_index()`

Comment: I am getting the same answer from the solution that I have provided as well. I just want to convert this to a dataframe so that I have right set of columns that can be read by pandas for further merge operations.

Comment: @jezrael: One more thing, How can I get the column names as shown in the output? I need to have the exact column names in my output

Comment: Use `df1=df.set_index(['ID','Rating_Year'])['Rating'].unstack().add_prefix('Rating_Year_').reset_index()`